# Swift rightbar button item padding issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a right bar button item but I want to remove paddinf of it.I have looked all question here I tryied some of them such as fixedspace and image inset but it does not solve my problem.When I use image inset , it did not work all device.
[image: I want to remove padding and adjust my other buttons]

Comment: So what is the question actually? I am a bit confused. Which button on the screenshot is problematic, what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @Pancho I said it was about my right bar button. There is an eye icon at the top right in the picture, I want to slide it to the right